# redirect std::cout to a custom writer

Tags: c++, stream, stringstream, iostream, streambuf

I want to use this snippet from [Mr-Edd's iostreams article](http://www.mr-edd.co.uk/?p=16) to print std::clog somewhere.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;

    // Make clog use the buffer from oss
    std::streambuf *former_buff =
        std::clog.rdbuf(oss.rdbuf());

    std::clog << "This will appear in oss!" << std::flush;

    std::cout << oss.str() << '\\n';

    // Give clog back its previous buffer
    std::clog.rdbuf(former_buff);

    return 0;
}
```

so, in a mainloop, I will do something like

```
while (! oss.eof())
{
    //add to window text somewhere
}
```

Here's the [ostringstream docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) but I'm having trouble understanding the best way to do this.  I have a method that displays the text, I just want to call it with any data in the ostringstream.

What is the easiest/best way to get anything sent to std::clog redirected to a method of my choice?  is it as above, and fill in the while !eof part (not sure how), or is there a better way, say by overloading some 'commit' operator somewhere that calls my method?  I'm loking for quick and easy, I really don't want to start defining sinks and such with boost iostreams as the article does - that stuff is way over my head.

Comment: could you be more clear on what your question is?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I encourage you to look at [`Boost.IOStreams`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html). It seems to fit your use-case nicely, and using it is surprisingly simple:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/concepts.hpp> 
#include <boost/iostreams/stream_buffer.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bio = boost::iostreams;

class MySink : public bio::sink
{
public:
    std::streamsize write(const char* s, std::streamsize n)
    {
        //Do whatever you want with s
        //...
        return n;
    }
};

int main()
{
    bio::stream_buffer<MySink> sb;
    sb.open(MySink());
    std::streambuf * oldbuf = std::clog.rdbuf(&sb);
    std::clog << "hello, world" << std::endl;
    std::clog.rdbuf(oldbuf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your snippet works in a blank project.  i copy-pasted your sink into my real project and copied your main into an init method somewhere, changed NOTHING, and I get several pages of boost nonsense errors.

Comment: (on this line: bio::stream_buffer<MySink> sb;)

Comment: I'd love to help, but would need more information about the errors you see. The draconian size limit on the comments does not make it practical here, so I suggest you post your code and the errors it generates on the Boost users list. http://www.boost.org/community/groups.html#users

Answer (score 8):

I **think** you want to pull the text from the ostream while it's not empty. You could do something like this:

```
std::string s = oss.str();
if(!s.empty()) {
    // output s here
    oss.str(""); // set oss to contain the empty string
}
```

Let me know if this isn't what you wanted.

Of course, the better solution is to remove the middle man and have a new streambuf go wherever you **really** want it, no need to probe later. something like this (note, this does it for every char, but there is plenty of buffering options in streambufs as well):

```
class outbuf : public std::streambuf {
public:
    outbuf() {
        // no buffering, overflow on every char
        setp(0, 0);
    }

    virtual int_type overflow(int_type c = traits_type::eof()) {
        // add the char to wherever you want it, for example:
        // DebugConsole.setText(DebugControl.text() + c);
        return c;
    }
};

int main() {
    // set std::cout to use my custom streambuf
    outbuf ob;
    std::streambuf *sb = std::cout.rdbuf(&ob);

    // do some work here

    // make sure to restore the original so we don't get a crash on close!
    std::cout.rdbuf(sb);
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: i didn't expect it to be anywhere near that simple, but i'll give it a try.

Answer (score 6):

I needed to grab outputs to std::cout and std::cerr from third party libraries and log them using log4cxx, and still retaining the original outputs.

This is what I came up with. It's pretty straight-forward:

- I replace the old buffer of an ostream (like std::cout) with my own class so that I get access to what ever is written to it.
- I also create a new std::ostream object with the old buffer so that I can continue to get the output to my console, besides sending it to my logger. Which I find kind of handy.

Code:

```
class intercept_stream : public std::streambuf{
public:
    intercept_stream(std::ostream& stream, char const* logger):
      _logger(log4cxx::Logger::getLogger(logger)),
      _orgstream(stream),
      _newstream(NULL)
    {
        //Swap the the old buffer in ostream with this buffer.
        _orgbuf=_orgstream.rdbuf(this);
        //Create a new ostream that we set the old buffer in
        boost::scoped_ptr<std::ostream> os(new std::ostream(_orgbuf));
        _newstream.swap(os);
    }
    ~intercept_stream(){
        _orgstream.rdbuf(_orgbuf);//Restore old buffer
    }
protected:
    virtual streamsize xsputn(const char *msg, streamsize count){
        //Output to new stream with old buffer (to e.g. screen [std::cout])
        _newstream->write(msg, count);
        //Output to log4cxx logger
        std::string s(msg,count);
        if (_logger->isInfoEnabled()) {
            _logger->forcedLog(::log4cxx::Level::getInfo(), s, LOG4CXX_LOCATION); 
        }
        return count;
    }
private:
    log4cxx::LoggerPtr _logger;
    std::streambuf*    _orgbuf;
    std::ostream&      _orgstream;
    boost::scoped_ptr<std::ostream>  _newstream;
};
```

Then to use it:

```
std::cout << "This will just go to my console"<<std::endl;
intercept_stream* intercepter = new intercept_stream(std::cout, "cout");
std::cout << "This will end up in both console and my log4cxx logfile, yay!" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Could eke out some performance by moving the std::string contruction inside the isInfoEnabled check.

Comment: This works great! I only changed intercept_stream to take a std::string instead of char const* since getLogger takes a string and moved the string construction inside isInfoEnabled check per Rhys Ulerich's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

For the log4cxx example you must override overflow() and sync() otherwise the badbit is always set after first stream is received.

See: 
http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/fd9d973282e0a402/a872eaedb142debc

```
InterceptStream::int_type InterceptStream::overflow(int_type c)
{
    if(!traits_type::eq_int_type(c, traits_type::eof()))
    {
        char_type const t = traits_type::to_char_type(c);
        this->xsputn(&t, 1);
    }
    return !traits_type::eof();
}

int InterceptStream::sync()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the contents of the ostringstream, then use its str() member. For example:

```
string s = oss.str();
```