# It's possible suppress output about of one function?

Tags: c++

In my program I use an external function which generates output to me and I don't want it not to be generated by that function alone,
it's possible?

```
int main()
{
    int a; 
    //I don't want the output of this function
    a = function();
    
    //now i want output
    cout << "the result is : " << a; 
}
```

Is it possible?

### EDIT:

The function is in an external library.

Comment: `cout <<`  very strongly suggests C++, but the C tag hints that the external function is NOT C++. That's an assumption, though. Can you clarify? In pure C++ it's easy.

Comment: That's why a function should do only one thing (computation and display are two things).

Comment: if by any means you can modify `function` it should at least take the stream as parameter, so you can easily redirect output

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I not written function(). It's external.

Comment: what does function do?

Comment: i understood that. Often we have to make compromises and apply workarounds. In a perfect world `function` would not write to `std::cout`. It does so, but among all workarounds changing `function` would be the best option

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816994/how-to-disable-printf-function seems releated to this one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppress output to cout from linked library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576024/suppress-output-to-cout-from-linked-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only standard C++ where no `dup`-like functions exist, you could open a temporary `std::FILE` and `std::swap` with `stdout`.

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

// extern "C" int function(); // an assumption

// A helper class to temporarilly redirect the output to stdout to a file and to read
// the content of the file afterwards.

class BufferStdout {
public:
    // the collector string is used for collecting the output to stdout
    BufferStdout (std::string& collector) :
        m_collector(collector),
        fp(std::fopen("output.txt", "w"))
    {
        if(fp == nullptr) throw std::runtime_error(std::strerror(errno));
        std::swap(stdout, fp); // swap stdout and the temp file
    }

    ~BufferStdout () {
        std::swap(stdout, fp); // swap back
        std::fclose(fp);

        // read the content of the temp file into m_collector
        if(std::ifstream is("output.txt"); is) {
            m_collector.append(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is),
                               std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{});
        }
        std::remove("output.txt"); // cleanup
    }

private:
    std::string& m_collector;
    std::FILE* fp;
};

int main()  {
    std::string collector; // the string that will contain the output from function()
    int a;
    {
        BufferStdout foo(collector);
        a = function();
    }
    std::cout << "the result is : " << a << '\n';
    std::cout << "Collected from function():\n";
    std::cout << collector << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Note: It needs C++17 or later because of `if(std::ifstream is("output.txt"); is)` - if that's a problem, let me know and I'll make it work in C++11 or 14 instead.

Comment: @EliaTolin Glad to hear it! You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is generally possible but a bit complicated, a similar question is in [Suppress output to cout from linked library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576024/suppress-output-to-cout-from-linked-library)

In addition to you can *redirect stdout* before invoking the shared library function and then redirect it again after the use of the shared library function in the however this is also a suboptimal solution. Best solution would be to adapt the shared library

```
// Cpp program to redirect cout to a file 
#include <fstream> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 



using namespace std; 
  
int main() 
{ 
    fstream file; 
    file.open("cout.txt", ios::out); 
    string line; 
  
    // Backup streambuffers of  cout 
    streambuf* stream_buffer_cout = cout.rdbuf(); 
    streambuf* stream_buffer_cin = cin.rdbuf(); 
  
    // Get the streambuffer of the file 
    streambuf* stream_buffer_file = file.rdbuf(); 
  
    // Redirect cout to file 
    cout.rdbuf(stream_buffer_file); 
  
    cout << "This line written to file" << endl; 
  
    // Redirect cout back to screen 
    cout.rdbuf(stream_buffer_cout); 
    cout << "This line is written to screen" << endl; 
  
    file.close(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

> Note: The above steps can be condensed into a single step

```
auto cout_buf = cout.rdbuf(file.rdbuf())

// sets couts streambuffer and returns the old 
streambuffer back to cout_buf
```

source :  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/io-redirection-c/

Comment: I think OP want to have the output in the program, only later, so perhaps you could redirect it to a `stringstream` instead of a file?  +1 anyway.

Comment: I think it works when you write output with cout. But i have external function from external library. 
I tried but not works.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, i think C++.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
fclose(stdout);
```

with this function you will suppress any printf inside your libraries.
Of course you can not print other stuff inside your software.

Comment: I interpret OP:s question and comment to ralf's answer as the output from `function()` is wanted, only not right away. This will discard it completely. Also, I'm pretty sure `/dev/stdout` doesn't exist on all platforms.

Comment: i changed the answer now :)